# Why doesn't == implementation call Equals for Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, equals-operator

I've seen in the souce code of the GUID type in the .NET Framework that the implementation of [Equals](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/54bcc19a4028b3f2.html) and the `==` operator execute very similar code.

Why doesn't the `==` operator call the Equals method on the firts argument? Something like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(Guid a, Guid b)
{ 
    return a.Equals(b);  
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based, we can't read the framework designers/developers minds.

Comment: I think its because of primitive vs Object issues

Comment: My guess would be that the operator implementation existed prior to the addition of `IEquatable` to the framework.  When that was added, they chose to duplicate the operator code rather than rewrite it (perhaps a policy of avoiding changing old code?)  This is pure speculation, though.  Could also be an extremely minor optimization consideration for more aggressive inlining, but wouldn't strike me as a particularly worthwhile reason for code repetition in this case.  Or it was just a mistake and nobody in code review thought it was bad enough to be worth the effort to fix.

Comment: I don't think the linked duplicate question actually answers this question, in case of `Guid` it is a value type, thus it can't be null. Re opening the question..

Comment: For the case of `Guid`, as the implementations are the same it **could** call `Equals`, however, in doing so it would proceed further into the stack, and add unnecessary overhead. Likewise, if for whatever reason the implementation of `Equals` ever *needs* to be different than `==`, the base implementation of each is already separated, and no refactoring needs done. Also, as @Habib said, this isn't necessarily the same question as was marked duplicate due to context, I would suggest adding `for Guid` to the title.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET there are plenty other questions on implementation details of the .NET Framework, and sometimes they receive really good answers by people who know a lot or even MS employees. You shouldn't close this just because *you* cannot answer.

Comment: @Stijn I agree you (or I) shouldn't close because we do not know the answer. However, "Why does the framework do X" or "Why is this framework implemented in Y way" are inherently opinion-based, as there are innumerable reasons why the design team *could* have made one decision or another. They are unanswerable since no one outside of such a team can provide a reasonably definitive answer.

Comment: Adding to Bradley's comments - what difference does it make?  Sure it's interesting but unless there's a meaningful technical reason it just comes down to coding style.

Comment: If you are wondering if *you* should use your proposed implementation, please ask that (as it can be answered objectively) and use the Guid code as an example if you feel it is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment is very telling:

> ```
> public static bool operator ==(Guid a, Guid b)
> {
>     // Now compare each of the elements
> ```

This doesn't make sense by itself. Looking for that comment elsewhere in the file:

> ```
> public bool Equals(Guid g)
> {
>     // Now compare each of the elements
> ```

but also

> ```
> // Returns true if and only if the guid represented
> //  by o is the same as this instance.
> public override bool Equals(Object o)
> {
>     Guid g;
>     // Check that o is a Guid first
>     if(o == null || !(o is Guid))
>         return false;
>     else g = (Guid) o;
>
>     // Now compare each of the elements
> ```

The comment only makes sense in that last method. This is a very strong indication that the `Guid.Equals(Object)` implementation came first.

It would be bad, or at least sub-optimal, if `Guid.operator ==` and `Guid.Equals(Guid)` were implemented on top of `Guid.Equals(Object)`, as that last method *requires* pointless allocations, and while it will hardly be noticeable in the common cases, there are certainly `Guid` comparisons that happen in some code in tight loops where the allocations would be measurable.

Now, it would certainly have been possible to make `operator ==` use `Equals(Guid)`, or vice versa, but it really isn't any additional work to copy and paste it twice instead of once.

Comment: By the rather dull comments, like "first check this is a GUID", it seems that this perhaps was implemented by a rather new developer, who might not be familiar with the DRY principal :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Also that the `o == null` is redundant: if `o == null`, then `!(o is Guid)` is necessarily true.